# If cell equals specified text then run macro

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have VBA code which creates a new workbook based on a template and saves it with a name based on a list.

I only want the code to create the workbooks IF a statement is true.

See following example:

Sheet "MC_TestSheetGenerator"
[image]

The macro `ONE_CreateTestsheetWB_TEST_NEW_INST_01` creates new workbooks based on a template called "TEST-NEW-INST-01" and saves the file with the name in col "I" of "MC_TestSheetGenerator".

How can I only do that if the adjacent cell H equals "TEST-NEW-INST-01"?

In this example it should only create two new workbooks as the value is only present in row 3 and 8.

```vb
Sub ONE_CreateTestsheetWB_TEST_NEW_INST_01()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim wb As Workbook, sh1 As Worksheet, lr As Long, rng As Range
Set sh1 = Sheets("MC_TestSheetGenerator") 'Edit sheet name
lr = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = sh1.Range("I3:I" & lr)
    For Each c In rng
        Sheets("TEST-NEW-INST-01").Copy 'Edit sheet name
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        wb.Sheets(1).Range("A3") = c.Value
        wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & c.Value & ".xlsx", 51
        wb.Close False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside your For loop just add an If statement using property OFFSET :

```
For Each c In Rng
    If c.Offset(0, -1).Value = "TEST-NEW-INST-01" Then
        Sheets("TEST-NEW-INST-01").Copy 'Edit sheet name
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        wb.Sheets(1).Range("A3") = c.Value
        wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & c.Value & ".xlsx", 51
        wb.Close False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
Next
```

> [Range.Offset property
> (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset)

Also, as advice, I'm pretty sure your `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` could be outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

OFFSET property will be the easiest way to introduce it in your code OR you can change the loop type and loop directly in that column and check the condition after.

Also, I agree with @Foxfire And Burns And Burns, the `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` should be set outside the loop, preferably at the end of the code/sub.

I have revamped your code, please have a look:

```
Sub ONE_CreateTestsheetWB_TEST_NEW_INST_01()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wb As Workbook, wbnew As Workbook
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, lr As Long, rng As Range
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set sh1 = wb.Sheets("MC_TestSheetGenerator")
lr = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To lr
    If sh1.Range("H" & i).Value2 = "TEST-NEW-INST-01" Then
        Set wbnew = Workbooks.Add
        wb.Sheets("TEST-NEW-INST-01").Copy Before:=wbnew.Sheets(1)
        wbnew.SaveAs wb.Path & "\" & sh1.Range("I" & i).Value2, FileFormat:=51
        wbnew.Close
    End If
Next i

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This loop would be faster indeed than a `For Each`, good re-coding! As a suggestion, notice you defined `wb` undeclared, so it's a variant type, not Workbook type, I think it should be `Dim wb as Workbook, wbnew As Workbook`. Anyways, upvoted.

Comment: You are right, I have missed that part.I have edited the answer.Thank you for the feedback!